# (How) can I implement futures & promises in C++03?

Tags: c++

My company is frozen at C++03. I have a concurrency problem which can be implemented in a straightforward manner using future & promises (see [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/284544/blocking-function-call-with-asynchronous-content/284556#284556)), which are not available until C++11.

What are my options? I am hoping for some tried & tested FOSS. Failing that, how would I implement similar functionality?

Comment: does this not boil down to multi-threaded application? and maybe a thread-pool in the background to limit the resources used ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/thread) provides what you want, see [Futures](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures)

Comment: Can you believe that I am still struggling to get permission to use Boost?  Q#*§"$%!!